# Rails and Ransack searching non persisted models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, ransack

I normally use Ransack to be able to filter data for a user and will_paginate to paginate it.

Now I need a view, where I have records that do not exist yet in the database.
Those are records that should be created this year, but they are not.

My question:
How would you solve the problem with the not persisted records in a database. How do I give it to the view? How do I make them searchable and paginatable. 
I already looked at [ActiveModel::Model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html), but it is hard so search thru something not persisted.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I'm guessing your doing something like bulk importing a bunch a data which your users then filter and choose what to save? Creating a paginated collection is pretty easy: [`WillPaginate::Collection.create`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/WillPaginate/Collection). But figuring out where to paginate if your data is not the same on each request is going to be difficult.

Comment: I am trying to show users a list of Interviews, that have to be created this year. So there are not persisted yet.